# Why does it take so long for Gravatar to update my StackOverflow avatar?

Tags: support, profile-page

Why does it take so long for Gravatar to update my StackOverflow avatar?

Comment: *head explodes*

Comment: This question has been asked before, but it may have been deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't take long for them to update your avatar, **if** you click on logout.

If you look at a version of your avatar that hasn't been cached, it will show your new avatar immediately.

I once prevented it from updating the cache by continuing to log into Gravatar.com

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't take them long. What takes long is for the cache to expire on the old one.