# why the profile picture is not changing?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does it take so long for Gravatar to update my StackOverflow avatar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24205/why-does-it-take-so-long-for-gravatar-to-update-my-stackoverflow-avatar)

i'd changed my profile picture at gravater.com before 2 days but till now it hasn't changed in stackoverflow.com 
How do i change it ??? is there any caching problem ??
thanks for help ...

Comment: Out of votes, dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24205/why-does-it-take-so-long-for-gravatar-to-update-my-stackoverflow-avatar

Comment: i went to gravater.com and delete the old picture form there website 
and changed my browser , after doing all that the picture has been changed successfully , but what is the problem

Comment: Picture was stuck in your cache.

Comment: Voted, since you're to hasty to spend your votes on crap we dont need.

Comment: You only get 12 close votes a day and this is the second day in a row of maxing out from all the dupes.

Comment: Excuses excuses!